# opencv kmeans doesn't classify data in some classes

Tags: opencv, k-means

I'm trying to implement [Scalable Recognition with a Vocabulary Tree](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAG&url=http://www.vis.uky.edu/~stewe/publications/nister_stewenius_cvpr2006.pdf&ei=aHjzUZSHKZCu4QT7qoFY&usg=AFQjCNGM50w5493n0IDBtFdQ5C4q3SVPFQ&sig2=cE4cakwD4-J8AmGTmIJFbg&bvm=bv.49784469,d.bGE)
 and I'm using opencv kmeans function to cluster feature vectors so I put all my vectors in one Mat object and pass it to the function like this:

```
TermCriteria criteria;
criteria.epsilon = 0.1;
int attempts = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS;
int K = 10;
Mat Centers;
Mat Labels;

kmeans(descriptors, K, Labels, criteria, attempts, flags, Centers);
```

So in the function fills "Centers" and "Labels" Mat objects like this:

```
Centers has K rows, 64 columns (I'm using SURF features) and one channel

Labels has as many rows as "descriptors", one column and one channel and it's values are in the range of [0 K-1]
```

These are the things I have checked. After I do this to all the vectors I copy vectors with the same label to a new Mat and pass it to the function again.

My problem is that sometimes one of the values in the range [0 k-1] is missing in "Label" so none of the feature vectors is classified in that cluster. I've checked it for different K's and It usually happens at least once at some level (never in the first call though). Even for K = 3.

I assume at those times the data I pass to the function is not right. So my question is that when could this happen? What things should I check on the data that I pass to the function to make sure they are valid?

Also if you have a link of any good implementations of the paper I would really appreciate it if you post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some times some clusters have less than K number of members in them so in the next level the function returns an error. Though I still haven't figured out why sometimes a cluster is empty.